# Using TimelineJS and AMD

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, timeline.js

I'm looking for a way to use TimelineJS with RequireJS's implementation of AMD. I can get things partially working, e.g.

```
define(["storyjs", "timelinejs", ...], function(storyjs, timelinejs, ...) {
    createStoryJS({
        type:       'timeline',
        width:      '800',
        height:     '600',
        source:     { ... }, // sample JSON
        embed_id:   'timeline-embed'
    });
});
```

The above produces a timeline, but `storyjs` (which exports `VMM` in my RequireJS config) always attempts to perform its own loading of the TimelineJS libraries, which invariably produces errors in the Firebug/developer tools console.

I'm either looking for a way to programmatically build the TimelineJS object (which I couldn't find any examples of), tell StoryJS to not bother loading libs using its mechanism (because I've already provided them) and in general integrate TimelineJS with an AMD solution.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

RequireJS configuration used, below. For my own personal use I have a tendency to rename JS libraries and append their version numbers.

```
var require = {
    waitSeconds: 5,
    paths: {
        "app": "../js/app"

        // ** Libraries
        ,"backbone": "../js/lib/backbone-1.1.0.min"
        ,"bootstrap": "../js/lib/bootstrap-3.0.2.min"
        ,"jquery": "../js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min"
        ,"jquery-ui": "../js/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min"
        ,"json2": "../js/lib/json2"
        ,"underscore": "../js/lib/underscore-1.5.2.min"

        // ** TimelineJS
        ,"storyjs": "../js/lib/storyjs-embed-2.0.3.min"
        ,"timelinejs": "../js/lib/timeline-2.26.3.min"

        // ** RequireJS Plugins
        ,"domready": "../js/lib/plugins/requirejs/requirejs-plugin-domready-2.0.1"
        ,"i18n": "../js/lib/plugins/requirejs/requirejs-plugin-i18n-2.0.4"
        ,"text": "../js/lib/plugins/requirejs/requirejs-plugin-text-2.0.10"
    },

    shim: {
        'backbone': { deps: ['underscore'], exports: 'Backbone' }
        ,'bootstrap': { deps: ['jquery'] }
        ,'jquery': { exports: '$' }
        ,'json2': { exports: 'JSON' }
        ,'storyjs': { exports: 'VMM' }
        ,'timelinejs': { deps: ['storyjs'] }
        ,'underscore': { exports: '_' }
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you include this RequireJS config you're mentioning? Since the call to `createStoryJS` is not qualified it looks like you're using browser's globals, not the AMD-loaded dependencies.

Comment: @kryger Updated the question with the RequireJS config. Even if I used the AMD-loaded dependencies to call `createStoryJS` (e.g. `VMM.createStoryJS(...)`, and I'm not sure that this even works) would the issue still be that StoryJS is attempting to load libraries using its own mechanism? Thanks!

Comment: I may have figured out how to get this working without running through the `createStoryJS()` method. Once I'm confident I'll refine the code and post as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It took digging into the TimelineJS source a bit to see what exactly `createStoryJS` was actually doing and then looking at some of the other source code, but I finally answered my own question. In fact, it is relatively straightforward and very similar to my early attempts to make this work before posting my question above to StackOverflow.

#### RequireJS Config:

```
// RequireJS config
var require = {
  waitSeconds: 5,
  paths: {
    ...

    // ** TimelineJS
    ,"storyjs": "../js/lib/plugins/jquery/storyjs-embed-2.0.3.min"
    ,"timelinejs": "../js/lib/plugins/jquery/timeline-2.26.3.min"

    ...
  },
  shim: {
    ...
    ,'storyjs': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: 'VMM' }
    ,'timelinejs': { deps: ['jquery', 'storyjs'] }
    ...
  }
};
```

#### Module instantiating TimelineJS object:

```
define([ "json2", "timelinejs"], function(JSON, timelinejs) {
  var js_version = "2.24",
    config = {
      version: "2.24", // DEFAULT: 2.x
      debug:   true,
      type:    'timeline',
      source:  {...} // Sample JSON
  };
  var timeline = new VMM.Timeline("timeline-embed", 800, 600);
  timeline.init(config);
});
```

This is, at the very least, one example for handling the TimelineJS instantiation using RequireJS/AMD; it is also how I've decided to solve my original issue.

Comment: +1 For showing how to initialize the timeline without using `createStoryJS`.